# Where is Django code inside my Django Application?

Tags: django

When I created a Django application, where is the code of Django? I mean, the source code of the framework my app is using?

Context: I've been receiving a NoReverseMatch error, and I think my urlpatterns are ok, so I want to debug the reverse function to see why it's failing.

Comment: Show your `urls.py` and `views.py`.

Comment: It's wherever `pip` installed it to. Very much depends on what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

All the code is the directory where you ran this command to start your project:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Since you are getting NoReverseMatch you need to post the contents of the url.py file both from your main project (this folder will have wsgi.py in it as well) and urls.py from the app in case you made it too. Otherwise nobody knows what is going on with your project